# how to avoid variable replacement with ansible

Tags: ansible

I am having a playbook like

```
- name: Set Config Knox - knox-config
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:8080/api/v1/clusters/{{ cluster_name }}"
    method: PUT
    force_basic_auth: yes
    user: "{{ ambari_admin_user }}"
    password: "{{ ambari_admin_password }}"
    body: "{{ lookup('template','templates/knox/knox-config.json') }}"
    body_format: json
```

In general this works fine. But now I have in the `knox-config.json` itself content which container `{{}}`. Now it tries to replace it with variables, that doesn't exists.

Any idea how to avoid the variable replacement in the uri module of ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the lookup plugin with `template`, so i suppose this invokes the jinja2 templating engine and this is why the replacement its done.

To make jinja "ignore" the `{{` and `}}`, you need to somehow replace them with `{{ '{{' }}` and `{{ '}}' }}` respectively.

hope it helps.